# multiple checkbox sum and totals in php-loop

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql

my problem is to get a dynamic total for each checkbox group coming from a PHP loop
unique array-items comes from mysql database loop

```
<?php 

$price_list = array(1, 7, 8, 10, 12, 15);

foreach($price_list AS $price){ ?>
    
<div>
    <span>Price-Group <?php echo $price;?></span>
    <form method="post" action="">
      <input type="text" value="20.50" id="price<?php echo $price;?>"><br>
          Option 1<input type="checkbox" value="1.50" data-id="<?php echo $price;?>"><br>
          Option 2<input type="checkbox" value="2.50" data-id="<?php echo $price;?>"><br>
          Option 3<input type="checkbox" value="3.50" data-id="<?php echo $price;?>"><br>
      <input type="text" id="total<?php echo $price;?>" value="20.50">
  </form>
</div>
<hr>

<?php } ?>
```

and here is my problem jquery-code (i need a dynamic total)

```
<script>
$('input:checkbox').change(function(){

    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    var total = parseFloat($('#price'+id).val());

  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function(){
      total += isNaN(parseFloat($(this).val())) ? 0 : parseFloat($(this).val());
  });

  $('#total'+id).val(total);

});
</script>
```

Comment: I [tested your code](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/OJZmJJb), and it seems to do what it is programmed to do. Please clarify your question.

Comment: if there is only one group with a total, it works.
there are several sums/totals from the loop. when different groups are checked, there are incorrect totals in the total variable in the jquery code. Thank you

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your problem. Never include pseudo-code like `while (...)`.

Comment: sorry for the pseudo code, i improved the code.
the sum of the checkbox values ​​in a group should only be summed in a group in the total field and should not be summed to other totals. Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

OK, I spotted a problem in your Javascript. In the middle you do:

```
  $('input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {....});
```

and this function is therefore applied to all checked checkboxes. You only want to apply the function to checked checkboxes in the pricegroup, to which the checkbox that changed belongs. Something like this:

```
  $('#form' + id + ' input:checkbox:checked').each(function () {....});
```

Now you don't have a form id, so I had to add that. See: [code example](https://codepen.io/kikosoft/pen/OJZmJJb).

Note that you don't have to give each checkbox an individual `data-id`, because from them you can access the form id. For instance, when a checkbox changed:

```
var id = $(this).parent().attr('id');
```

would give you the whole form id.